# Google Analytics SiteSpeed - Higher than expected compared to other speed metrics?

Tags: google-analytics, page-speed

Any reason that Google Analytics SiteSpeed would consistently be 2 seconds higher than expected?  We've tried using various website speed tests online (pingdom shows sub 3 seconds, etc) - along with testing on various actual devices/locations.

Our PageSpeed Insights scores are in the 97+ range, as are our scores on most other similar services (pingdom, etc).  We're also using many things which should speed things up, such as mod_pagespeed, gzip, optimized images, AWS / Cloudfront, etc.

However, our SiteSpeed via Google Analytics is consistently in the 4-5 second range.  Are there any factors that could affect Analytics exclusively, that would inflate the SiteSpeed ranges incorrectly?  If not, are there any other suggestions on an approach we should take here to bring them down?

Answer (score 1):

Factors that can affect website performance accuracy.

- Analytics tag placement location
- Manually increase the Sitespeed sample rate to test a larger percentage of visitors
- Create a custom script to test speed and then compare with Google's numbers

I recommend adding your analytics tag immediately following the head tag.

Make sure you keep other JavaScript files at the end of the page, unless they are specifically needed at the top.

Minify and combine CSS, JS and HTML for additional speed boosts. There is actually a very easy way to do this by modifying your http.d file if you use Apache.

Answer (score 1):

You'll always get the Site Speed score higher when you looking into Google analytics because Google is testing the Site Speed from many different geographic regions and shows an average of it and not from only one geographic location which you are seeing in many 3rd party tools.

So if you want to improve the the load time in all geographic regions, I suggest using CDN which can accelerate the data delivery speed in across the globe and you'll see an increase in Speed.